# How to execute a command in elisp (startup script) whenever a new term is created?

Tags: term, ansi-term, comint

I tried adding hook to term-mode-hook to call comint-send-string:

```
  (add-hook
   'term-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (comint-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) "alias t='echo test'")
  ))
```

But I got `(error "Buffer *ansi-term* has no process")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `term-exec-hook` is a variable defined in term.el.
>
> Called each time a process is exec'd by `term-exec`.
> This is called after the process is cranked up.  It is useful for things that
> must be done each time a process is executed in a term mode buffer (e.g.,
> `set-process-query-on-exit-flag`).  In contrast, `term-mode-hook` is only
> executed once, when the buffer is created.

I would also use the term API for sending input to the process, rather than using `comint-send-string`.

> `term-send-string` is a compiled Lisp function in term.el.
>
> `(term-send-string PROC STR)`
>
> Send to PROC the contents of STR as input.
> This is equivalent to `process-send-string`, except that long input strings
> are broken up into chunks of size `term-input-chunk-size`.  Processes
> are given a chance to output between chunks.  This can help prevent processes
> from hanging when you send them long inputs on some OS's.

Comment: Thanks!  Following codes work for me:
`
  (add-hook
   'term-exec-hook
   (lambda ()
     (term-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) "alias t='echo test'\n")
     ))
`